# ArrayList.contains() equals false when string is found in ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, excel, arraylist, cjk

I am trying to categorize Chinese words and characters by seeing which ArrayLists they are contained in. I have extracted Chinese characters from an excel file like this

```
public static List<String> hskOne = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskTwo = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskThree = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskFour = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskFive = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskSix = new ArrayList<String>();

public static List<String> hskOneUTF = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskTwoUTF = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskThreeUTF = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskFourUTF = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskFiveUTF = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> hskSixUTF = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws InputMismatchException {  

    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(HSKFILE));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Sheet> sheets = workbook.sheetIterator();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Extracting HSK 1 words to list


        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskOneUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskOne.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // Extracting HSK 2 words to list

        for (int i = 6; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskTwoUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskTwo.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // Extracting HSK 3 words to list

        for (int i = 12; i < 24; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 25; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskThreeUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskThree.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // Extracting HSK 4 words to list

        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
            for (int j = 25; j < 50; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskFourUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskFour.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // Extracting HSK 5 words to list

        for (int i = 24; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskFiveUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskFive.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }

        // Extracting HSK 6 words to list

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            for (int j = 50; j < 100; j++) {
                Cell cell = workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(i).getCell(j);
                String cellValue = charToUTF(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
                hskSixUTF.add(cellValue);
                hskSix.add(dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell));
            }
        }   
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the method charToUTF converts the character to its UTF-8 value, and I am filling two sets of arrayLists: One with the words converted to UTF-8 and the others not.
Here is the charToUTF method I am using:

```
public static String charToUTF(String str) {
        String encoded = "";
        for(char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
            encoded += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch | 0x10000).substring(1);
        }
        return encoded;
    }
```

You can find the excel file I'm using at https://www.chinesezerotohero.com/hsk-word-vis/. Each colored section of that file pertains to a different arraylist, and all list values are mutually exclusive.

My issue is when I run `hskFive.contains("会计")`, it evaluates to false when I checked that the list hskFive does in fact contain this value. I've checked for hidden spaces and switching to traditional arrays but nothing has worked so far. Could someone tell me why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: if, before your hskFive.contains call, you do hskFive.add with the string, I'm sure you will find that contains returns true. And I also bet that if you print out all the of hskFive, you'll probably now see the value at least twice. The problem is likely to be that you have two nearly identical looking strings

Comment: @ControlAltDel could I check for nearly identical strings using .trim()?

Comment: You could try. Just FYI In unicode there are some characters that look VERY VERY similar, especially given how the font they are displayed in chooses to display them. I don't know what else to tell you

Comment: @ControlAltDel Okay thanks I will try that

Answer (score 0):

On the page you linked there is an invisibe character (it seems to be U+200B, a zero width space) after the first symbol, which isn't present in the string you posted. The other characters seem to be the same, but you should be careful about similar looking characters anyway.

If you are sure that it isn't important, you could remove it before searching for matching entries. It may also be a flaw in the original excel file. Since I don't know much about character encoding, I tracked this probem mostly by using search tools in my browser and other applications, which are usually well written and/or widely bug tested and better than your eyes with this kind of tasks.

Your string:

会计

The excel string (check on the site if it is fitered out):

​
会​计

There are probably some good reasons to use this character and it is used often (probably on every entry) in the linked page, but in most cases it just causes problems and confusion and should be avoided, unless you know what you are doing and have a good reason to use it, so your program is probably not the problem. If there is a reason to use it, you should account for it in your code and you probably have better tools than me to do it, otherwise improving the original file or give the maintainers a hint about the problem would be a better course of action and ignoring the character would give a temporary fix.

EDIT: Zero width space is often used in languages where visible space between words isn't used (wikipedia gives japanese as an example and chinese is likely to belong to the same cathegory).